# Nativescript Angular router 3.0.0-alpha.7 - Navigation failure

Tags: angular, router, nativescript

Problem showcased on this project example: https://github.com/rrcoolp/test-router-app/

Navigation failure: I have created this test project to present an issue with the NATIVESCRIPT ANGULAR 2 (RC3) Nativescript with router  3.0.0-alpha.7

The issue is simple, navigation to another page fails after first navigation. To see problem in action follow these steps:

1. Click on any BUTTON (GOTO PAGE 1 or GOTO PAGE 2): after first click the respective page and it's content is rendered
2. Any subsequent clicks to either of the buttons (including CHILD components) fail in navigation

Any help would appreciated...

Here is a sample of my APP_COMPONENT file:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from "@angular/core";
import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "nativescript-angular/router";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "./app.routes";
import {Location, LocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";
import {app_globals} from "./utils/globals";

@Component({
 selector: "main",
 directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
 providers: [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
 templateUrl: "masterpage.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 showBackButton: boolean = false;
 history: any = [];
 pushState: any;

 constructor(public _router: Router, private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private _Location: Location, private _LocationStrategy: LocationStrategy, private _app_globals: app_globals) {
  this._changeDetectionRef = _changeDetectionRef;
  this._LocationStrategy = _LocationStrategy;
 }
 ngOnInit() {
  this._app_globals.navigateTo$.subscribe(val => {
   console.log("SUBSCRIBED NAVIATE TO:" + val);
   this.navigateTo(val);
  });
 }


 goBack() {
  this._LocationStrategy.back();
 }
 navigateTo(page) {
  console.log("GotoTestPage"+page);
  this._router.navigate(["testpage"+page, "PAGE"+page]).then(() => {
   alert("Route Completed but see content didn't change to PAGE"+page);
   
  });
 }

 GotoTestPage2() {
  this.navigateTo("2");
 }

 GotoTestPage1() {
  this.navigateTo("1");
 }
}
```

Comment: Make sure app router providers are only defined once. Try moving those providers to the bootstap method only. I can take a look later if that doesn't work. In a cafe right now.

Comment: I have not tried using the router outlet yet `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` could you add a base route for it? https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/ng-sample/app/examples/router/router-outlet-test.ts#L67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by specifying absolute path in the navigate method(add a leading "**/**"):

```
this._router.navigate(["/testpage"+page, "PAGE"+page]).then(() => { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander Vakrilov, I figured the same yesterday - but ran into a completely different problem after upgrading to RC4 and rputer 3.0.beta.2...See the latest code in the GIT REPO - and please advise if you have any ideas...Thanks again

https://github.com/rrcoolp/test-router-app